# Add a confirm bootstrap modal/dialog to checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a form checkbox inside map. When unchecked I want the user to get a bootstrap confirm dialog to ask "are you sure you want to turn off switch?" before the handle command.

code:

```
command.onAdd = function (map) {
      var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'command');
      div.innerHTML = '<form><input id="command" checked="true" type="checkbox"/>switch</form>'; 
      return div;
};
command.addTo(map);

document.getElementById("command").addEventListener("click", handleCommand, false);

function handleCommand() {

    if(this.checked == true){

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) as a convenient way to do this:

```
function handleCommand() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if (!checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                // your code
            } else {
                checkbox.prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```